# Unit and Integration Test for Azure Function with ServiceBusTrigger

Tags: unit-testing, azure-functions, azure-servicebus-queues

I have an Azure Function which is triggered by an **Azure Service Bus Queue**.

The function is below.

1. How this Run method can be unit tested?
2. And how an integration test can be done by starting with `AddContact` trigger, checking the logic in the method and the data being sent to a blob using the output binding?

```
    public static class AddContactFunction
    {
        [FunctionName("AddContactFunction")]
        public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("AddContact", Connection = "AddContactFunctionConnectionString")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message: {myQueueItem}");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How this Run method can be unit tested?

The method is a static public method. You can unit test it by invoking the static method `AddContactFunction.Run(/* parameters /*)`; You will not need a Service Bus namespace or a message for that matter as your function expects to receive a string from the SDK. Which you can provide and verify the logic works as expected.

> And how an integration test can be done by starting with AddContact trigger, checking the logic in the method and the data being sent to a blob using the output binding?

This would be a much more sophisticated scenario. This would require to run Functions runtime and generate a real Service Bus message to trigger the functions as well as validate that the blob was written. There's no integration/end-to-end testing framework that is shipped with Functions and you'd need to come up with something custom. [Azure Functions Core Tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local) could be helpful to achieve that.

Comment: I tried to follow this [GitHub project](https://github.com/jeffhollan/functions-test-helper) to do integration testing. It was written two years ago, and the projects don't compile because the namespace  ```Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs``` is no more supported. I looked at the link that you provided, but that does not give a sample for integration testing.

Comment: That was a project from a PM on the Functions team. I'll try to ping him to see if there's a better suggestion.

Comment: Don't really have anything to add.

Answer (score 16):

I had the exact same doubts.
Adding Unit Tests is not too complicated, at the end of the day, its a function, so all we got to do is to call the Azure Function with the correct string, for parameter `string myQueueItem`.

Adding **Integration tests** needs some additional ground work. In the [Github project](https://github.com/jeffhollan/functions-test-helper), the author uses the `TestFunctionHost` class from [Azure/azure-functions-host](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/blob/dev/test/WebJobs.Script.Tests.Integration/TestFunctionHost.cs) project.

I tried following this strategy, but the amount of code needed to setup all these is uncomfortably high for my liking. Not a lot of it is well documented, and some of the stuff needs developers to use [Azure App Services myGet feed](https://www.myget.org/F/azure-appservice/api/v3/index.json).

I wanted a simpler approach, and thankfully I found one.
Azure Functions is built on top of the [Azure WebJobs SDK package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs), and leverages its [JobHost](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/JobHost.cs) class to run. So in our integration tests, all we need to do, is to setup this Host, and tell it where to look for the Azure Functions to load and run.

```cs
IHost host = new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureWebJobs()
        .ConfigureDefaultTestHost<CLASS_CONTAINING_THE_AZURE_FUNCTIONS>(webjobsBuilder => {
            webjobsBuilder.AddAzureStorage();
            webjobsBuilder.AddServiceBus();
        })
        .ConfigureServices(services => {
            services.AddSingleton<INameResolver>(resolver);
        })
        .Build();

using (host) {
    await host.StartAsync();
    // ..
}
...
```

Once this is done, we can send messages to ServiceBus and our Azure Functions will get triggered. Once can even set breakpoints in the Functions getting tested and debug issues!

I have [blogged about the whole process here](https://dev.to/sntnupl/test-driven-development-of-azure-functions-with-c-part-3-integration-tests-5116) and I have also created a github repository [at this link](https://github.com/sntnupl/azure-functions-sample-unittest-integrationtest), to showcase test driven development with Azure Functions.

Comment: This is perfect! I was finally able to get this running, and can debug and step through my running functions during my integration tests! But for some reason the IWebJobsExceptionHandler isn't catching unhandled exceptions to fail the test. Is there something else I need to do with dotnet 6 to get exception handling working?

Comment: Not sure, haven't looked into this.

Comment: This looks like just what I need - but one of my functions is a Http trigger. I've added `webJobsBuilder.AddHttp()` and it seems to run fine, but I cannot see what the URL/Port is or anywhere to set this?