# How to test Azure durable function with service bus message trigger

Tags: azure, unit-testing, .net-5, xunit, azure-durable-functions

I have created a Azure durable function with service bus topic trigger. How do I write unit test for the starter function below:

```
[FunctionName(nameof(SampleStarter))]
        public static async Task SampleStarter(
            [ServiceBusTrigger("%topicName%", "%topicSubscription%",
            Connection = AppConstants.ServiceBusConnectionString)] Message message,
            MessageReceiver messageReceiver,
            string lockToken,
            string messageId,
            [DurableClient] IDurableOrchestrationClient starter,
            ILogger log)
        {
        }
```

Comment: You can refer to [Writing unit tests for orchestration functions in Azure Durable Functions](https://laurentiu.codes/2020/11/05/writing-unit-tests-for-orchestration-function-in-azure-durable-functions/), [Unit and Integration Test for Azure Function with ServiceBusTrigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62749060/unit-and-integration-test-for-azure-function-with-servicebustrigger) and [Durable Functions unit testing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-unit-testing)

Comment: I had gone through them before. Didn't meet my requirement.

Comment: @DeepDave-MT sure, thanks for your help.