# xUnit test for Azure Service Bus Topic trigger

Tags: c#, azure, moq, azureservicebus, xunit

I am new to xUnit and Azure Service Bus. I could not find unit test examples using xUnit framework. Appreciate your help in giving me some sample code which shows how I can mock and write the test for the below function?

```
    [Function("ReceiveMessageFromTopic")]
    public void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("myTopic", "myTopicSubscription", Connection = "ServiceBusConnection")] string triggeredMessage)
    {
        ExpectedMessage receivedMessage = new();
        _logger.LogInformation($"ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message: {triggeredMessage}");

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(triggeredMessage))
        {
            _logger.LogError("Empty message.");
            return;
        }

        try
        {
            receivedMessage = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ExpectedMessage>(triggeredMessage, JsonSerializationOptions);
        }
        catch (JsonException ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Invalid message.");
            return;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex, "Unexpected Error.");
            return;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please refer [Creating Unit Tests For Azure Functions](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/creating-unit-tests-for-azure-functions/)

Answer (score 0):

To do the xunit test with service bus trigger using azure function you can find the sample code in this [**`Github link`**](https://github.com/jeffhollan/functions-test-helper)

For more information please refer this [**`SO THREAD`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62749060/unit-and-integration-test-for-azure-function-with-servicebustrigger) as suggested by @*Sean Feldman* and this [**`Blog|.NET: Unit Testing Azure Service Bus`**](https://www.mrjamiebowman.com/software-development/dotnet/net-unit-testing-azure-service-bus/)

Comment: This link [Github-link](https://github.com/jeffhollan/functions-test-helper) doesn't cover Service Bus. Please check.